# Pass a Date Range from a Web Scrape Function to a Loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops, web-scraping, range

I'm running a web scrape with Python that grabs data and imports it to a SQL DB. The scrape works fine. I would like to use a date variable to historically fill the DB. The date is also key for the URL in the scrape. I've made the scrape a function:

```
def scrape(date):
   url = "https://address%s.csv" %(date.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
   #do stuff to import to SQL DB
```

So I would define a date range and then for each day in the range, run my scrape and import by passing the date from the loop. Something like:

```
start_date = pd.datetime(2020, 1, 1)
end_date = pd.datetime(2020, 1, 3)
for n in range(int(start_date.day), int ((end_date - start_date).days), 1):
    scrape(n)
```

Here my result is that I am passing an integer which will not work.  I need to pass the actual date to the function from each iteration of the loop.  So in this case I would do the scrape for Jan 1, 2020, and Jan 2, 2020 and import the resulting data to my DB, after which the code would be complete.

I'm agnostic what kind of loop I would use as long as I can define the date range.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are searching for [`pandas.date_range()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html#pandas-date-range) function:

```
def scrape(date):
    print(date.strftime("%Y%m%d"))  # now just print the date
    # url = "https://address%s.csv" %(date.strftime("%Y%m%d"))

start_date = pd.datetime(2020, 1, 1)
end_date = pd.datetime(2020, 1, 3)

for d in pd.date_range(start_date, end_date):
    scrape(d)
```

Prints:

```
20200101
20200102
20200103
```

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on similar code. You can refer to the Github link [generating dynamic URL with date](https://github.com/prakharjhudele/Web-Scraping/tree/master/Using%20Request_BeautifulSoup).!

Comment: Thanks.  Really was only looking for an efficient way to loop through the date range here and pandas built in function seems to do that